# Receiving [Error: NOT_FOUND] when running a Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When I call the function from my React-Native app it throws this error: `[Error: NOT_FOUND]`.

I researched it and according to Firebase documentation that means: "**A specified resource is not found, or the request is rejected by undisclosed reasons, such as whitelisting.**"

Here is the entire console log message:

> [05:51:32] I | ReactNativeJS ▶︎ 'ERror handled', { [Error: NOT_FOUND]
>                                │ line: 26115,
>                                │ column: 28,
>                                └ sourceURL: 'http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false' }

**React-Native code:**

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('registerNewPatient')({
  email: 'bimiiix@hotmail.com',
  password: 'bbbbbb1'
}).then((onfulfilled, onrejected) => {
  if (onfulfilled) {
    console.log("OK callback function:", onfulfilled);
  } else {
    console.log("Error callback function:", onrejected)
  }
}).catch(error => { console.log("ERror handled", error) })
```

**Cloud function:**

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!data.email) throw "Missing email parameter";
    if (!data.password) throw "Missing password parameter";
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password,
        disabled: false
    })
        .then(function (userRecord) {
            registeredUser = userRecord.uid;
            console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        });
    return registeredUser;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As highlighted in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#initialize_the_client_sdk):

> **Note:** To call a function running in any location other than the default `us-central1`, you must set the appropriate value at initialization. For example, on Android you would initialize with `getInstance(FirebaseApp app, String region)`.

For the Firebase Javascript SDK, this method is [`firebase.app.App#functions(String region)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App#functions).

So to use the Cloud Function in region `europe-west3` as above, you need to change

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('registerNewPatient')(/* ... */)
```

to

```
firebase.app().functions('europe-west3').httpsCallable('registerNewPatient')(/* ... */)
```

or

```
const functionsEUWest3 = firebase.app().functions('europe-west3');
functionsEUWest3.httpsCallable('registerNewPatient')(/* ... */)
```

Comment: Good catch Sam!

Comment: Now I am having this error: [Error: INTERNAL]. I tried returning only the email + password from the function and it did return so sending parameters is being done correctly, the problem should be somewhere in the admin.auth(). Do I actually need some special permissions to create new users? Whats the difference if I just use auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword ? How does the function know if I am an admin or not?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @samthecodingman excellent answer about regions, you're also not handling asynchronous APIs correctly in your code. By the time your `return registeredUser` now runs, the `registeredUser = userRecord.uid` hasn't been called yet. I recommend using some additional logging statements to troubleshoot this type of behavior in the future.

This should be closer:

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!data.email) throw "Missing email parameter";
    if (!data.password) throw "Missing password parameter";
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;

    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        password: password,
        disabled: false
    })
    .then(function (userRecord) {
        return userRecord.uid;
        console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('Error creating user', error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I am having this error: [Error: INTERNAL]. I tried returning only the email + password from the function and it did return so sending parameters is being done correctly, the problem should be somewhere in the `admin.auth()`. Do I actually need some special permissions to create new users? Whats the difference if I just use `auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword` ? How does the function know if I am an admin or not?

Comment: When you're running the Admin SDK on Cloud Functions, so you have administrative privileges by default. You can't "just use `aut(). createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, as that method doesn't exist in the Admin SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth

Comment: ok, I just thought of something else. Can I actually call that function if I am not even authenticated in the client app? I did not implement authentication in RN yet because I am just trying to test that function.

Comment: Btw I am not trying to create new Admins, I want to create new simple users. Does the function that I am using creates new Admins or just users? I am totally confused!

Comment: @bmmf "can I call the function if not authenticated?", as it is written, yes. You will need to check the [`context.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) property to restrict the function based on the caller. "Does this create normal users?", also yes. When Frank refers to an admin above, they are referring to the Admin SDK (`firebase-admin`), a server-side SDK that is treated as an admin with full control over your project. Because of that, unless you check the value of `context.auth`, any user who calls this function will be able to create users.